# Proof of existing path on Depth-First-Search spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G$ be an undirected connected graph, and $T$ the directed spanning tree of $G$, which I got by performing a DFS on $G$. If $H$ is a complete subgraph of $G$, how can I proof that there a path in $T$ exists which passes all nodes in $H$? And is it possible that that path passes other nodes, which are not in $H$?

Comment: I've tried visualising the problem with some examples, and even though it seems so easy, I can't seem to mathematically formulate a proof. (It seems trivial; "T connects all nodes, so there should be a path from node $i$ to node $j$ if $i,j \in G_1$..")

Comment: Your last quote is not exactly right, e.g. if your graph has $4$ vertices and looks like letter $Y$, then $T$ would connect all the vertices, but there is no path that connects all of them at once.

Comment: "Let $H$ be a complete subgraph of $G$, with nodes $i,...,n$. Let $i$ be the first node that is encountered in the DFS. Because $G$ is undirected, the DFS will encounter all nodes $i+1,...,n$ in the iteration within $i$. Therefore, $T$ will contain a path connecting nodes $i,...n$." (Am I on the right track here?)

Comment: The quote is right, since there is no complete subgraph of $G$, so the theorem doesn't apply then.

Comment: You are on the right track, but your claim is too weak -- it does not imply that there is a path, only that there is a subtree starting with $i$ which contains all the other vertices.

Comment: But since $T$ is directed, creating directed vertices to each newly 'discovered' node, doesn't that imply that there is a path? Every node in $H$ is discovered within the iteration of $i$...

Comment: Well, the theorem is true, so it works, but your argument isn't enough to prove it, there are missing fragments and saying "it's obvious" won't help anybody. You need to make your proof so that each step follows from the previous one, and there are no leaps. So don't ask me to give you a counterexample, because one does not exist, and despite that, your proof isn't sound.